# Drive sharing popup won't open

Tags: google-drive-api

I'm trying to integrate the "Drive share" popup in my app, following this how-to: https://developers.google.com/drive/manage-sharing#launching_the_google_drive_sharing_dialog_in_your_app

Everything ran well, until I effectively open it.
After few seconds I get an error message:

The console contain this error: "Refused to display 'https://drive.google.com/share?id=0BzH05IFzFfzuZWdXYzZPZHRkaUk&foreignServi…tr.apps.googleusercontent.com&embedOrigin=http%3A%2F%2Fvideo.unishared.com' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'. "

I suppose that it's related to this requirement: "The URL of the page that launches the dialog must have the same origin as the Open URL registered for the app." but here this is the case.

I can't figure out what's wrong here.
Thanks for your help.

**EDIT**

Some of ours users had reported this issue which is happening randomly, on different browsers.
It is not fully solved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok I've just figured out what was wrong with my implementation.

I was using the App ID that you can find for your client in API console, "API access" tab (something like ...apps.googleusercontent.com)

I've just found an other id in the "Drive SDK" tab, just below the title. When using it the popup finally show up!

Comment: Do you need Drive SDK enabled for sharing files? I have Drive API is that not enough? I am also getting the same error.

Comment: Hi, yes you need to enable the Drive SDK to make it works. The app ID to use to create the popup is the one indicated just below the title "Google Drive" in the Drive SDK tab in the API console.

Answer (score 0):

You should allow your embed origin as a whitelisted Javascript origin on [API Console](https://code.google.com/apis/console/b/0/). I'm sorry I can't give you a direct link, but it's under API Access tab.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer! I've already setup these origins: "http://video.unishared.com
http://staging.unishared-gae.appspot.com
http://localhost:8080" and it doesn't solve this issue.
The doc is not mentionning this field, it only says that the origin must be the same than the Open URL.

Comment: Also need to install the app -- add the drive.install scope when you authorize. 

'errorMessage': "No application with ID \x22107160330549\x22 is installed.",

After adding install scope:

'errorMessage': "Sorry, the item(s) you requested are not available.",

The 2nd error likely coming from the fact that the ID was hardcoded to something not owned by me.

Comment: Thanks Steve for your answer. The app is always installed on my side. ID is not hardcoded as you can see here: https://gist.github.com/arnaudbreton/5398733

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple constraints:

- The JS origin needs to match the Open or Create URL in Drive SDK settings
- The app needs to be installed.

From trying your demo, it appears the issue is the fact it isn't installed. The error (burried in the body of one of the responses) is:

```
'errorMessage': "No application with ID \x22107160330549\x22 is installed.",
```

After adding install scope:

```
'errorMessage': "Sorry, the item(s) you requested are not available."
```

The 2nd error likely coming from the fact that the ID was hardcoded to something not owned by me.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Steve.
On my side, the app is always installed.

Id is not hardcoded, it is passed when invoking the popup, here's the code used to achieve: https://gist.github.com/arnaudbreton/5398733

Is there a way to workaround the matching open URL restriction? I need to test it but don't want to do it on my production instance. Maybe create a "staging app"?

Comment: Yes, create a 2nd app for dev/staging and set the URLs appropriately (FYI, I use https://forwardhq.com/ for proxying to my laptop which works nicely and gives me stable URLs) There are some bugs filed to relax these restrictions or make them more flexible, but no ETA on when those changes will be made.

Comment: Ok I'll try that, thanks for your answer. 

I had briefly tested on production yesterday, with correct URL but doesn't work either.

Comment: Ok, I've just setup a staging app with a correct staging URL (http://staging.videnot.es) both in App Engine / Drive SDK in API console. Sharing popup still don't load but I got a different error: "Uncaught Error: SyntaxError: DOM Exception 12" in 2939790373-v2-doclist_share.js:14327. Line 14327 matches with pretty printed (in Chrome) JS version.

Comment: Can you send me a link to your staging instance?

Comment: Actually I did in my last comment: http://staging.videonot.es or http://staging.unishared-gae.appspot.com Thanks for your help!